# Prove that $TQBF \notin SPACE(n^{\frac{1}{3}})$

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

I would like some hints on how to approach this problem, I know for instance that $TQBF$ is $PSPACE$-$Complete$, so it can solved in poly space and any other $PSPACE$-$Complete$ problems can be log spaced reduced to $TQBF$. I believe that I need to employ the space hierarchy theorem in some way but I am not sure how, this is a homework question so I just want a hints. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot give you any more hints than the facts you've already mentioned.

Comment: By the way, TQBF being PSPACE-complete means that TQBF is in PSPACE, and *any* problem in PSPACE is polytime-reducible to it. (Perhaps even logspace-reducible.)

Comment: Thanks we were told that it is logspace reducible. I understand that you cannot give anymore hints without basically spelling out the solution. I will think more deeply about this question. Have a good evening @YuvalFilmus

Comment: This is actually not quite as easy as I had assumed.

Comment: @Yuval, this is an exercise in Sipser about padding IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument is actually surprisingly delicate. This sketch follows Tompa's *Introduction to computational complexity*, [Chapter 10](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/complectures/books/T/Ch10.pdf). The space hierarchy theorem shows that there is some problem $L \in \mathrm{SPACE}(n^{1+\epsilon}) \setminus \mathrm{SPACE}(n)$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. Since TQBF is PSPACE-complete, there is some logspace reduction from $L$ to TQBF. But we actually know more - using Savitch's theorem, we can come up with some reduction which blows up instances of $L$ of size $n$ to instances of TQBF of size $O(n^{2(1+\epsilon)} \log n)$ (at least according to Ryan Williams, [page 1 at the bottom](http://www.stanford.edu/~rrwill/qbf-lower-bd.pdf)). If TQBF were solvable in space $O(n^\delta)$ then this would give an algorithm for $L$ in space $O(n^{2\delta(1+\epsilon)})$. Taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$, this shows that $\delta \geq 1/2$.

Comment: Hey @YuvalFilmus if you are interested in the solution to this problem, here is another version of this problem with exponent $n^{\frac{1}{4}}$ as solved by Professor Cook  - http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/csc463h/problems/solutions4.pdf it's question 4

Comment: Different notions of reductions are used in different places.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to derive that TQBF is indeed complete using logspace reduction. But I still have some question about what "blowing up" instances mean in your answer. I'm trying to prove by contradiction and somehow use the padding argument.

Comment: More specifically, I'm wondering how we can put an upper bound on the size of the output of the logspace reduction to TQBF.

Comment: Ah, sorry...I see it now, it's bounded by Savitch's theorem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks for the answer but I think this part of your answer **"Since TQBF is PSPACE-complete, there is some logspace reduction from L to TQBF"** is a bit misleading and it needs a change. please look at the https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/90527/is-every-pspace-complete-problem-complete-with-respect-to-logspace-reductions .