# LogSpace reductions vs. PTime reductons for defining PSpace-completeness

Tags: reductions, space-complexity

Continuing [Is every PSPACE-complete problem complete with respect to logspace reductions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/90527/is-every-pspace-complete-problem-complete-with-respect-to-logspace-reductions) : earlier, PSPACE-completeness was defined via logspace reductions (e.g., cf. http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/Papers/LowerBounds.pdf), whereas it is defined via ptime reductions nowadays (e.g., cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE).

Why has it changed? Is it just because the folks after Dexter Kozen got too lazy even to **say** that one can go the extra mile to show that their reductions are actually logspace, let alone actually going that extra mile? Or is there a deeper, technical reason?

Crosspost: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/45709/logspace-reductions-vs-ptime-reductons-for-defining-pspace-completeness

Comment: This is to some extent arbitrary, and may require a historical investigation. For this reason, perhaps it's better to ask this on the "grown up" site [cstheory.se].

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thx; asked there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was posted on CSTheory, and we don't allow simultaneous cross-posting.